# Oracle if statement in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT
       CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS(:DATEINPUT, 1), 'MM') = '10' 
            THEN
                TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS(:DATEINPUT, 1), 'MM')
            WHEN SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS(:DATEINPUT, 1), 'MM'), 1, 1) = '0' 
            THEN
               SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS(:DATEINPUT, 1), 'MM'), 2, 1)
            ELSE
               SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS(:DATEINPUT, 1), 'MM'), 1, 2) 
         END
            AS CUR_MONTH_FRMTD,
       P.OPR_DATE,
       P.INDICE,
       P.LOAD_TYPE,
       P.CONTRACT_MONTH,
       P.CONTRACT_YEAR,
       P.VALUE,
       P.DATE_INSERTED,
       P.DATE_UPDATED
  FROM ZE_DATA.PWX_FWD_CURVE P ) Q
  WHERE
  Q.LOAD_TYPE = 'HLH'
  AND Q.INDICE = 'MidC'
  AND Q.CONTRACT_YEAR = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'YYYY') 
  AND Q.CONTRACT_MONTH = Q.CUR_MONTH_FRMTD
  AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'MM') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'MM')
  AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'YY') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'YY')
  AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'DD')
```

It works great to narrow down the record to the day it was inserted, returning just one record as required. But the problem is that no records are inserted on Saturday or Sunday, breaking the filtering's usefulness.

For Saturday or Sunday I'd need to get Friday's data. I thought logic such as below would work. But this can't be done in oracle SQL.

```
  IF TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'DAY') = 'SATURDAY' THEN
  WHERE
  ....
  AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT-1, 'DD')
  ELSE IF TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY' THEN
  WHERE
  ....
  AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT-2, 'DD')
```

At this point I need to make this work in a select statement. Can't use stored procedure. Can anyone think of a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an IF why not just a nested or like this

```
Where ...
  AND 
    (
        (TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'DAY') = 'SATURDAY' AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT-1, 'DD'))
        OR 
        (TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY' AND TO_CHAR(Q.DATE_INSERTED, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(:DATEINPUT-2, 'DD'))
    )
    AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, if I've understood the requirement:

```
where  q.date_inserted =
       case to_char(:dateinput,'fmDy','nls_date_language = English')
           when 'Sat' then :dateinput -1
           when 'Sun' then :dateinput -2
           else :dateinput
       end;
```

(It gets slightly more complicated if the date column and parameter can contain times. If the date column isn't indexed or a partition key then you could just put `trunc()` around everything; if it is then it might be worth constructing a `between` expression.)